# Mounting Case Sensitive ISO

Tags: centos, mount, iso

I have an ISO whose file names and directories are case sensitive. When I mount this in CentOS 7.6 using the method I have always used:

`sudo mount -t iso9660 -o loop /location/file.iso /mnt/iso`

The ISO mounts in all lower case file names and directory names. If I mount using the following:

`sudo mount -t iso9660 -o map=off /location/file.iso /mnt/iso`

Then everything is upper case (as expected). How can I mount and get the mixed case file names and directory names? I am able to mount it with the expected output on a MacOS system so I suspect I'm missing something in CentOS.

Comment: Did you try to create a iso image with mixed case filenames?

Comment: It was created by someone else. I know the mixed case works on other OS though and the mixed case is important for a script to run.

Comment: Well ask this person how it was created.

Comment: Have you experimented with other values for `-t`? E.g., `-t cdrom` or `-t hsfs` (instead of `iso9660`)? How do you mount it on macOS?  Can you run a `mount` command in macOS and see what options are used there?

Comment: In general, a properly created CD will display mixed-cased with `-t iso9660`.  For example, the distribution CDs do this.   `$ mount -r -o loop -t iso9660 CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1810.iso /mnt
$ ls /mnt
CentOS_BuildTag  GPL        RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7          images/
EFI/             LiveOS/    RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Testing-7  isolinux/
EULA             Packages/  TRANS.TBL                     repodata/
`   If you are not seeing case properly then the `TRANS.TBL` file is not present or incorrectly built.